# Put php variable in wordpress exclude array for tag cloud

Tags: php, arrays, string, wordpress, variables

I'm trying to exclude a tag from the wordpress tag cloud by it's slug.

What I have after a whole Saturday of searching and trying is this:

```
$term = get_term_by('slug', 'widget', 'portfolio-tag');
$term_id = $term->term_id;
$string_id = "'" . $term_id . "'";

add_filter('widget_tag_cloud_args', 'my_widget_tag_cloud_args');

function my_widget_tag_cloud_args($args) {

    $args['number']    = 0;
    $args['largest']   = 18;
    $args['smallest']  = 8;
    $args['unit']      = 'pt';
    $args['order']     = 'DESC';
    $args['orderby']   = 'count';
    $args['separator'] = ' ';
    $args['exclude']   = print_r($string_id, true);
    return $args;
}
```

I guess the above is not the best option i tried this afternoon, but it's the last one.
The piece of code below returns the number 18 if I use `print_r($term_id)` to check it:

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', 'widget', 'portfolio-tag' );
$term_id = $term->term_id;
```

If I use `$args['exclude'] = '18';` the tag named 'widget' gets exclude. The only thing I still haven't managed is to do something like this: `$args['exclude'] = $term_id;`

I know that the exclude parameter only accepts strings. The reason why I not just put 18 in there is because I like to share my theme with some artist-friends.

I've made a theme to show my paintings. I also made a widget that will show a random painting with the name 'widget'. Only it's useless to have that in the tag cloud. Believe it or not, but compared to my artist friends I'm by far the computer expert ;) So I want to keep it as simple as possible for them, just put the widget-tag to a painting and the rest will be taken care of - at least, that's the plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I can spot here is related to variable scope:

The `$string_id` you set is not available in the `my_widget_tag_cloud_args()` because you set it outside of that function.

So you need to move the code that generates it inside there or find another way to do the job, like using an [*anonymous function*](http://php.net/functions.anonymous) or by using an object for this.

```
$exclude_term_id = get_term_by('slug', 'widget', 'portfolio-tag')->term_id;

add_filter('widget_tag_cloud_args',
    function ($args) use ($exclude_term_id) {

        $args['number']    = 0;
        $args['largest']   = 18;
        $args['smallest']  = 8;
        $args['unit']      = 'pt';
        $args['order']     = 'DESC';
        $args['orderby']   = 'count';
        $args['separator'] = ' ';
        $args['exclude']   = $exclude_term_id;

        return $args;
    });
```

The other problems I've spotted are the use of `print_r` and then you wrap the actual ID inside single quotes. That is both not necessary. In PHP an integer number and a string are normally just interchangeable. If not, just *cast*:

```
add_filter('widget_tag_cloud_args', 'my_widget_tag_cloud_args');

function my_widget_tag_cloud_args($args) {

    $term = get_term_by('slug', 'widget', 'portfolio-tag');

    $args['number']    = 0;
    $args['largest']   = 18;
    $args['smallest']  = 8;
    $args['unit']      = 'pt';
    $args['order']     = 'DESC';
    $args['orderby']   = 'count';
    $args['separator'] = ' ';
    $args['exclude']   = (string) $term->term_id;
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a great explanation. I didn't even know PHP had a use keyword.

Comment: It's also a nice move here, because the code to initialize the `$exclude_term_id` is executed once only, not always when the cloud widget is filtered (okay, probably not the best example for it, because it would only need to be obtained if there is a widget at all, so the second example is better in this concrete case).

Comment: Great, your first suggestion works perfectly. And you, now you mention "The `$string_id` you set is not available in the `my_widget_tag_cloud_args()` because you set it outside of that function." it ofcourse makes perfect sense! Thanks for explaining me.
btw, I had also tried `(string)$term_id` before without success

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is scope. Variables that you've defined outside a function are no longer accessible within the function and cannot be modified unless you make the variable global in scope (ill-advised) or pass the variable by reference (not possible in this case).

In any case, you just need to put everything in scope:

```
add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'my_widget_tag_cloud_args' );
function my_widget_tag_cloud_args( $args ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', 'widget', 'portfolio-tag' );
    $args['number'] = 0;
    $args['largest'] = 18;
    $args['smallest'] = 8;
    $args['unit'] = 'pt';
    $args['order'] = 'DESC';
    $args['orderby'] = 'count';
    $args['separator'] = ' ';
    $args['exclude'] = (string)$term->term_id;     
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: this is better, because not all requests actually have the widget, so the code to obtain the ID is only executed when the widget is actually displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
$args['exclude'] = print_r($string_id,true);
```

should be

```
$args['exclude'] = array($term_id);
```

So, it could be

```
add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'my_widget_tag_cloud_args' );
function my_widget_tag_cloud_args( $args ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', 'widget', 'portfolio-tag' );
    // more args...
    $args['exclude'] = array($term->term_id);     
    return $args;
}
```

[A reference here.](http://designpx.com/tutorials/customize-tag-cloud-widget/)